# How to disable F10 default action in window (show window menu)?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

The default action of <kbd>F10</kbd> is to show the menu of the window.
However, I would like to disable this feature.

**UPDATED:**
Background: I would like to implement a special behavior in a JTextField if the user presses any key. Unfortunately, the JTextField don't get the event when <kbd>F10</kbd> is pressed because it is catched by the window (and the menu is shown).

Does anyone know how to disable this key binding in the window?

I tried to disable it in the root pane but without success:

```
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0), "none");
```

I searched a lot but found no solution for this issue. Maybe one of you knows an answer.

**UPDATE2**
Here a code example to reproduce this behavior:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    final JTextField edit = new JTextField();
    edit.setEditable(false);
    edit.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent ke) {
        edit.setText(KeyEvent.getKeyText(ke.getKeyCode()));
      }
    });

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("DEMO");
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.getContentPane().add(edit);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

}

Plase note: There is a different behavior according to whether "setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated" is set to true or false.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *"special behavior in a JTextField if the user presses the F10 key. "*  Why the F-10 key?  That seems counter-intuitive and an ingredient in an unusable GUI.

Comment: From everything I understand, `F10` is system key stroke used by the accessibility API to focus the menu bar and may not be "replacable"

Comment: First result from google [ java swing F10] search : http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18687.html

Comment: @Andrew: The user can customize the shortcuts. Therefore I am using a JTextField in which the user can specify the new shortcut for an action.

Comment: @Jack: There is no solution in the thread you are posting. There is a special solution for a single component only. However, I would like to completely disable this feature. I noticed that I made a mistake in my original post. I will update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried to disable it in the root pane but without success:

Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for the bindings of all Swing components.

You will see that the <kbd>F10</kbd> key is bound to the `JMenuBar`. So you should be able to use:

```
menuBar.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0), "none");
```

Edit:

Missed the point that you didn't have a menu bar.

It appears you can't just set the binding to "none". Looks like Swing is still searching up the tree to find an Action to execute. You need to provide a dummy Action that does nothing:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("do nothing");
    }
};

JPanel content = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
String key = "F10";
KeyStroke f10 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( key );
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(f10, key);
frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put(key, action);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your proposal. Unfortunately, it is not working because my frame has no menu bar (frame.getJMenubar(), frame.getMenuBar(), frame.getRootPane().getJMenuBar() returns null). It is not the menu bar which catches the F10 event, it is the menu of the title bar.

Here a screenshot: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3727/wjbasxml_png.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I did undertand you correctly , Create Keypressed event for your JTextField  on netbeans put to following code

```
private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       

   // Add below
       int key = evt.getKeyCode(); 

           if (evt.getSource() == jTextField1)
           {
               if (key == KeyEvent.VK_F10)
               {
                  // your actions here
                   System.out.println("Hello I am f10");

               }

           }
         //   end of if

        }
```